# PHP - Merging Form to Show Results on One Page Causing Issues

Tags: php, html, forms, api, magento

I previously had a HTML file containing a form separately from a PHP file containing the script which actions the form results - this worked perfectly without errors.

The problem with this is that the page would redirect to the PHP script whereas I prefer that the form results are shown on the same page so that the user can "search" again. When adding the PHP script on to the end of my HTML page and thus converting the HTML page to a PHP page, the following issues arise:

1) Error **"Notice: Undefined index: product_sku in /my_api.php on line 16"** is shown.

2) I added an `if` statement which will echo the text *"Product SKU xxx does not exist in the database."* if the variable that contains the results isn't set. This now shows permanently.

Screenshot of the results:

[image]

I assume these errors both occur because the form hasn't been submitted yet and therefore the posted form data and script results are not yet set. The results when submitting the form are still correct for both successful and unsuccessful queries, so the question is what do I need to do to do to have these two errors hidden before the form is submitted?

Please see my code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My API</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=/api.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        Enter a product SKU to get the price
        <form class="get_price" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="product_sku">
            <input type="submit" class="form_submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    /* Call form Submission SKU Field */
    $product_sku = $_POST['product_sku'];

    /* Variables */
    $callbackURL = "Edited";
    $temporaryCredentialsRequestURL = "https://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . URLencode($callbackURL);
    $adminAuthorizationURL = 'https://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/admin/oauth_authorize';
    $accessTokenRequestURL = 'https://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/oauth/token';
    $URL = 'https://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com';
    $apiURL = $URL . '/api/rest';
    $consumerKey = 'Edited';
    $consumerSecret = 'Edited';

    /* Create/Resume Session */
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
    }

    try {
        /* Variables */
        $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
        $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
        $oauthClient->enableDebug();

        if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
            $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestURL);
            $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
            $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
            header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationURL . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
            $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
            $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestURL);
            $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
            $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
            $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
            header('Location: ' . $callbackURL);
        } else {
            $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
            $resourceURL = "$apiURL/products/?order=entity_id&filter[0][attribute]=sku&filter[0][in][0]=" . $product_sku;
            //echo $resourceURL;
            //exit;
            $oauthClient->fetch($resourceURL, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'));
            $productList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
        }
    } catch (OAuthException $e) {
        echo '<pre>';print_r($e);echo '</pre>';
    }

    /* Get price of the product SKU */
    if ($productList) {
        foreach ($productList as $product) {
            echo '<br><br>Price of <b>' . $product_sku . '</b> is <span style="color: #ff0000; font-weight: bold;">£' . round($product->price, 2) . '</span>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<br><br>Product SKU <b>' . $product_sku . '</b> does not exist in the database.';
    }
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Once the form is submitted, you still need to be in the same page with the input typed after processing the PHP script? Also, you need to keep both HTML and PHP page separated from each other as well?

Comment: @Perumal93 I fixed it now with what nerdyist answered. Thank you for taking your time to look into this however.

Comment: Oh. That's nice. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple options

Rather than move your code to the form (because separating logic and view is a good idea) you could store the results of the query in the session and then redirect back to the form. Make the form a PHP page and then output what is in session for the results.

```
//Whatever come back from your query even an array
$_SESSION['query_result'] = "...";
//You can redirect by putting
//this at the end of the script
//This url should be what you have in the browser when on the form.
$urlForForm = 'www.sitename.com/products/search';
header('Location: '.$urlForForm);
```

Then change the html page to a php and have in there

```
<?php session_start();?>
<!--HTML FORM-->
<?php
//Check that value exists
if(isset($_SESSION['query_result'])){
    //If it does output it
    echo $_SESSION['query_result'];
    //unset it so it does not keep showing up
    unset($_SESSION['query_result']);
}
?>
```

If you want to keep them together as mentioned you could check if the value is set for that index

```
if(isset($_POST['product_sku'])){//Do stuff with SKU}
```

Or rather then checking specifically for a value to be set you could use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'` as a global check on the output logic. The only way you would have a POST request method is if the form was submitted.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //All your form processing and posting code.
    //Will only run when form is submitted
}
```

Comment: Yeah. That would take you to the page containing form. But the form data cannot be retained.

Comment: Okay I've added the redirect code just fine, so I just need to work out how to store the result of the script in a session and then output that result back on my form page?

Comment: Your if statement needs a closing bracket, but apart from that, this is absolutely perfect - you're awesome :) thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this using the following snippet.

```
$product_sku = "";

if(isset($_POST['product_sku'])){
$product_sku = $_POST['product_sku'];
}else {
echo "product doesn't exist in the database";
}
```

This way the error will only be shown when the form is not submitted, once the form is submitted the error will be gone.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to reply. I now receive the error "Notice: Undefined variable: product_sku". This is because the variable is used on line 54 as part of `resourceURL` so that correct API url can be retrieved (it appends the result of the `product_sku`). Maybe I need to shuffle my script positions around?

Comment: How about if I put the entire script below `session_start();` within the `if` statement?

Comment: Its not about shuffling the script, do one thing, the code which depends on or used the $product_sku variable put that in a single if statement i.e. if the variable is set then do the rest of things which depend on that variable else show the error message,,

Comment: Fyi `$product_sku = "";` would make isset return true.

Comment: oh yes,, then put and && condition within the if statement if(isset($_POST['product_sku']) && strlen($product_sku) > 0)

Comment: @muhammadwaqas I would just not set it. This is based on a value from POST and he looks to be checking $_POST directly. If there is nothing in the post it would be `null` which will return false with isset.

Comment: I put the code dependant on `$product_sku` in an `if` statement but ran into further errors because those variables were also dependant themselves. I'll have a think about this. Thank you.

Comment: If your form only contains one input field i.e. product_sku then why don't you put the entire PHP logic inside one if statement which ensures that product_sku has been set.

Comment: @muhammadwaqas I fixed it now with what nerdyist answered and could have it on sepearate files. Thank you for taking your time to look into this however.